# How to find this area of intersecting curves using integration?

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals, area

I have to find the area of the yellow part given $ABCD$ is a square of $10cm$ side and the curved lines that run diagonally are the circumference portions of the quadrants of circles with each side of the square as radius.

[image]

My attempt:-

I found out the equations of the curves as follows-.

$\color{red}{y=\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}$

$\color{blue}{y=-\sqrt{10^2-(x-10)^2}+10}$

$\color{green}{y=\sqrt{10^2-(x-10)^2}}$

$\color{violet}{y=-\sqrt{10^2-x^2}+10}$

Now,I know to find out the area of a curve using integration.

For the area under the red and blue curves bounded by $A$ and $D$ I found the are by-

$\displaystyle\int_0^{10}(\sqrt{10^2-x^2}-\sqrt{10^2-(x-10)^2}+10) dx$

But,I don't know how to extract the area of the yellow portion from this equation.

Please help me on how to continue.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: How I would approach this problem, would be to find the intersection point of the any two pair of curves, for example green and blue, and then use symmetry to compute only one quarter of the given figure, the bounds of integration given by the previously found intersection point. But the first task is simplified by the fact that you know that the intersection point lies on a specific line, so it should be easy to find.

Comment: Do you really need to do this via integrals? Could elementary geometrical methods work?

Comment: @ZainPatel Yes...you may give your method....

Comment: Do you really need to do it by integrating?

Comment: I have added a solution which relies only on basic geometric shapes... but I don't see it as more elegant

Comment: @cronos2 Any type of solution is accepted with pleasure...

Comment: if you want a geometric solution i have it

Comment: @superbjhon Thanks..but I have already received an answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested, we find the $x$ coordinate of the intersection point of the red and purple curves, which by symmetry has $y$ coordinate $5$, i.e. lies on the line $y=5$. Thus we solve the equation
$$\sqrt{10^2-x^2}=5\iff10^2-x^2=25\iff x=\pm5\sqrt{3} $$
of course we only keep the positive solution, which is 
$$x=5\sqrt{3}\leq 10$$
Now we divide the area into the four similar pieces and compute the area of the top right piece, which is the area between the purple curve $y=\sqrt{10^2-x^2}$ and the line $y=5$, so is given by
$$A:=\int_5^{5\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{10^2-x^2}-5dx=\frac{25}{3}(3-3\sqrt{3}+\pi)$$
The total area will then be equal to $4A$.

Another possible solution can be found without integration by adding up the blue and red (small triangle) areas in the following picture. These can be computed by elementary means. Of course finding the angle $\varphi$ might be somewhat hard (i.e. you might need trigonometry)

[image]

Comment: I have added a more elementary solution... although finding the angle $\varphi$ might be somewhat hard